# How is the 'search for tag' conducted?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, tags

In [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493145/do-you-tag-your-uiviews-or-retain-them-as-properties), a few answers reference searching the 'view hierarchy'. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12225184/on-ios-is-there-a-way-to-search-only-subviews-with-a-certain-tag) seems to indicate that the default is not to search 'branches' first.

Is this a search of the entire view hierarchy of the controller or just subviews of `superview` (below)?

For instance, assuming there is a button within a subview of the controller's view and that more than one of these buttons (in different subviews) exist and using this code:

```
- (IBAction)showInfo:(id)sender {
    [[sender superview] viewWithTag:2]
}
```

An alternate question is: Will duplicating the tag number cause the wrong view to be returned (again assuming different branches of the view hierarchy)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contained in the UIView Reference for `-viewWithTag:` is the following:

> Return Value
>
> The view in the receiver’s hierarchy whose tag property matches the
>   value in the tag parameter.
>
> Discussion
>
> This method searches the current view and all of its
>   subviews for the specified view.